# Why does this function return as 2

Tags: c, system-calls

I was trying to understand write function and its capabilities, I tried to write a function that gives the output of 5 since 5*10 is 50 but I could only write 1 byte I assumed that the output would be 5. Why is it 2?

```
#include <unistd.h>
void ft_putchar(int c){
    write(1, &c, 1);
}    
int main(){
    ft_putchar(5 * 10);
}
```

Comment: Note that the function does not return a value.  On a little-endian machine, it writes the character `2` to the standard output (on a big-endian machine, it writes a null or zero byte instead), but that's quite different from returning a value.

Comment: "I tried to write a function that gives the output of 5..." You're confusing integer values (binary representation of 50) with string values ( "50" )... If you want to see the first character digit of "50", you need to use `itoa()` or `sprintf()` first... AND, using '1' instead of `stderr` is a really bad practice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`5 * 10` is `50`. The character code `50` corresponds to the character `2` in ASCII. Therefore the output is `2` when interpreted as ASCII (or character code compatible to ASCII, such as UTF-8).

Also note that `int` has typically 4 (or 2) bytes. It looks like the first byte, which is written via the `write` function, contained the value `50` because it is less than 256 and you are using a *little-endian* machine.